# Best way to migrate 6k images from Access into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, csv

I wouldn't mind donating to anyone who helps me with this issue.

Should I store binary information with a BLOB data type? Should I store VARCHAR containing paths? I don't know how to do either of these automated at the moment. The images are currently embedded into an Access database as OLE Objects. This migration cannot be manual; it will have to be done automatically using scripts or programs because there are about 6k records.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: My take on this: save the path to the file in the database and the file on the FILE system.

Comment: It's much more efficient what @cularis said. Otherwise you end up scanning all the data of these big blobs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Leban's [OLEtoDisk](http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm) to export your images all at once. You can specify a "naming" column, your primary key for example, and constant fields to be appended/prepended to the naming column.

Your pictures are then called "exported1.jpg","exported2.jpg", ... assuming you choose to prepend exported and the id's where 1 and 2. It should be simple to move the files to a server and write a script to insert the correct paths into the MySQL database. Assuming this is a one time thing, because that's what it sounds like.

Just tested it with 4000 small (~150 kb) pictures, it was done in 2 minutes on a limited virtual machine. So 6000 should not be a problem.

Comment: Storing many images in the database is bad. Apart from performance issues, what happens when the database grows to millions of images? Use references to filesystems such as a zeropadded 64-bit index to represent the physical filename and derive the location from it eg. preg_match("/(...)(...)(..............)/", $index, $m). Match values $m[1]/$m[2]/$m[3].jpg gets the path/file in the directory tree:
imageroot/123/456/7890123456789.jpg You can adjust splits, and mount new devices to use multiple filesystems for growth. Backing up a database full of images every day would be really wasteful.